# Shared function - passing a variable

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble with the following function:

```
Public Shared Function VerificaEPessoaSingularObrigatorio(idRegisto As Long) As Boolean
        Return RepositorioEntidadesRegistadas.ObtemTipoEntidadeApenasSingular(ByRef BDContexto, idRegisto)
    End Function
```

I have to pass the BDContexto to the function "ObtemTipoEntidadeApenasSingular", but it has the following error: "BC30201: Expression expected.".

Do you know what the error might be?

Comment: It appears that you specified `Function` as the return type.  Was that your intention? VB.NET != Javascript.

Comment: @RobertHarvey `Function` is the appropriate keyword in VB.NET. The return type is specified as `As Boolean`, so the code posted is syntactically correct.

Comment: Oh, I see.  It returns a `Boolean`.  It's been awhile.

Comment: Where and how is `ObtemTipoEntidadeApenasSingular` declared, and where and how is `BDContexto` declared?

Comment: Remove `Shared` from the Function declaration.

Comment: @djv If I remove the shared it says that requires an object reference, is it because BDContexto is not initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ByRef in the parameter. That's supposed to be in the method definition.

```
Public Shared Function VerificaEPessoaSingularObrigatorio(idRegisto As Long) As Boolean
        Return RepositorioEntidadesRegistadas.ObtemTipoEntidadeApenasSingular(BDContexto, idRegisto)
    End Function
```

Comment: I've tried without the ByRef and it gave me this error:
"BC30369: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class."

Comment: @Araújo it means ObtemTipoEntidadeApenasSingular isn't a shared method, you need an instance of RepositorioEntidadesRegistadas to call that method.

Comment: what if I use "using" to initialize the RepositorioEntidadesRegistadas?

Comment: @Araújo "using" is useful when there's a destructor that need to be called like .Dispose().